# How to auto-scroll by Categories in Windows Store Apps?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a nested collection that I want to be able to format in a more user friendly way.

My nested collection is:

- Categories

  - Selectable Items

Currently what it looks like is a long horizontal scrollable ListView. If the Selectable Items are a lot for a category, it extends further and you need to keep scrolling to see the other Categories.

What I would like is, like a 2-part control, where you can see all of the Categories and when you 'click' the categories, it auto-scrolls / automatically to the proper Selectable Items.

I hope I make sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use one list. Fill it with categories at start and next (after click on category) fill it with items. Use some control to disaplay current category and after clicking on the control with current category name, fill the list again with categories.